# What other countries besides India use a Maximum Retail Price model?

Tags: india, regulations, price

India is the only country I have come across in my travels where it is mandatory to print the **Maximum Retail Price (MRP)** on any packaged items. On the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suggested_retail_price#India) for Suggested Retail Price, this fact is denoted as well.

**Are there any other countries which follow the same model as well?**

I'm not asking why others don't seem to follow it, but for vary consumers, this is a great way of avoiding being ripped off and usually prevents mark-up prices and disparities such as $0.25 cents in supermarket vs. $1 in the vending machine.

Comment: A very small number of items in the US have this, usually packaged snacks and drinks, but as far as I know it is not mandatory.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What you are talking about is an MSRP. That's a suggested price. The retailer has the ability to charge you higher or lower than this without any explanations. In India, the retailer cannot *legally* charge you higher than the MRP.

Comment: What's a “maximum retail price”? Who sets it?

Comment: @Relaxed The Maximum Retail Price is the maximum price at which the product manufactured by a company can be retailed. For instance Coca-Cola bottles have a maximum retail price of Rs. 30 on them and thereby it is *illegal* to sell them for more than that. The price includes any taxes which are levied. You can buy the product for lesser of course.

Comment: I saw that in Sri Lanka as well where items such as bottles of water have a fixed price wherever you buy them. In Europe, the only example I can think of is mobile phone prices (there is a maximum price for roaming fixed by the EU)

Comment: Sounds like a variation on the old Soviet concept the retail price is set by the government and is the same everywhere...

Comment: @uztop cigarettes have also fixed prices

Comment: @Karlson The prices are not fixed by the government. They is fixed by the original manufacturer.

Comment: @AdityaSomani Why would a manufacturer care how much you sell their product for?  If the product sells for more means there is a possibility to sell more of it at a higher margin in a particular locality.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic - I see economics, but don't really see the travel question in there...

Comment: @MarkMayo The travel question here is the fact that I don't want to get ripped off when I travel to other countries, where I assume that it's a suggested price where in fact I am being charged a higher price illegally. It does happen in India. Unwary consumers will be charged a higher price if they don't know about the MRP.

Comment: @Karlson: I am guessing here, but it sounds like the law requires the manufacturer to set a maximum price and the retailer to charge no more than that amount.  Presumably the manufacturer has some incentive to choose a price that is somewhat reasonable, as if they print INR 100000000 on a candy bar it will look like their intention is to enable retailers to gouge, which could be bad for PR.

Comment: @NateEldredge Absolutely. India has very stiff market competition and a very liberal media. If something like that were to happen, then the brand value will be damaged significantly. People will just buy some other competent product.

Comment: @NateEldredge My point exactly the only difference is that they don't set the price they force the manufacturer to do it but probably within strict limits, hence my comment.

Comment: @Karlson This is not true. The government has no control over that price marking. For instance bottles in restaurants are specially packaged with exorbitant MRPs and have printed on them "specially packaged for so and so restaurant" typically water bottles in restaurants cost 20 times as much.  So Rs. 300 instead of of Rs. 15. If they don't do that, someone can sue them for charging over the MRP for a bottle of water. It is just a law to print it on everything, in order to maintain transparency. The law does not control what price must be printed.

Comment: @AdityaSomani Just out of logic and economic basics.  If the retailer already paid the manufacturer for the their product and then resells it there is no point for the manufacturer to impose the MRP at which retailer can sell?  Especially the price that is reasonably limited.  If the manufacturer already got his money it becomes the retailers risk if they decided to overcharge so manufacturer has no interest in what happens to retailer because if there is demand others will fill the gap.  If law does not control what price is printed Infinity sounds like a reasonable MRP for all cases.

Comment: @AdityaSomani The government doesn't set the price it sets the maximum margin that can be imposed on the Product to about 30-50% so in essence imposing the maximum price based on the cost of manufacture.  Which is a variation on what SU was doing.

Comment: @Karlson This was implemented for the benefit of the consumer rather than the manufacturer or the retailer.

Comment: @AdityaSomani So was the Soviet Union's method look how that turned out...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16105/discussion-between-aditya-somani-and-karlson).